# Web API 2 CORS IIS Express Debug and No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors, iis-express, iis-10

Empty web.api project, install Microsoft.aspnet.webapi.cors 5.2.3, add

```
config.EnableCors();
```

to webapiconfig. make controller and action

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    [EnableCors("*" , "*" , "*")]
    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult("omg");
    }
}
```

Debug app and Load up fiddler and do a request to http://localhost:61939/api/Home

there are no CORS headers present. web.config contains:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

what am I missing? Why would this not insert an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in all request to my Get method?

Also the answer of defining CORS in web.config isn't an answer ... At some point I will need to add origin checking and potentially even checking the HTTP Method something like:

```
if(requestContext.HttpMethod == "POST" && (origin == "https://someplace.com" || origin == "http://localhost"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've done is enough to enable CORS, you can also enable CORS on all the controllers using this code :

```
 var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"); 
 config.EnableCors(cors);
```

I'm not sure how you're testing it, but note that only once the request contains the `Origin` header, it returns the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in reponse. If you omit the origin header in the request, the response wouldn't contain the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

[image: Request and Response Headers]

Comment: I'm not so sure I follow, i'm not using owin (app.UseCors)

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice it's not using pipelines .I've edited the answer, have another look

Comment: Your totally right that's all I was missing, thank you so much!

Comment: Wow, @akazemis .. your answer helped me solving my problem. I had the same case WebApi2 on IIS Express and not working only in Chrome and Firefox. What was wrong in my case was that I had a slash '/' on the end when configuring the allowed origin like http://localhost:xxxx/ .. So stupid by myself but it can happen to everybody. Hope that will help someone not having the struggle I had :D Have a nice day and thanks again!